# Calculating angles when sides are known - Without Trignometric ratios.

Tags: geometry, triangles

The question is:

> > ABCD is a parallelogram and BFDE is a square . If AB is 20 and CF is 16 what is the perimeter of the parallelogram.

[image]

The question is fairly simple and I know how to solve it. However how would I get the remaining angles of triangle FDC (highlighted) if i know that CD=20 and FD=12. I also know that angle F is 90 however the triangle doesn't seem to be 30-60-90 or a 45-45-90. Also I need to solve this without Trigonometric ratios since I wont be using calculator

Comment: Your question is basically "What are the angles of a 3-4-5" triangle, which is pretty googlable.  The short answer is that you need to use trig functions to express these numbers.

Comment: I realize that but I could obtain these angles using trigonometric ratios. I was just curious if it was possible to obtain them without trigonometric ratios which i guess is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The triangles $\,ABE\,,\,CDF\,$are congruent, thus $\,CD=20\,$. Apply now Pythagoras and get $\,FD^2=20^2-16^2=144\Longrightarrow FD=12=FB=ED\,$ , so $\,AD=BC=16+12=32\,,\,AB=CD=20\,$ and now just add.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question.

Comment: Thanks.. for pointing that out. The other question is could the angle C be determimined here ? Assuming only triangle DFC was in the picture ?

Comment: I am more interested in finding out if its possible to obtain angle C. Without considering the rest of the parallelogram

Comment: The angle is not at all pleasant. In particular (in radians) it is not a rational multiple of $\pi$.